# how to select a table in mysql_query php

Tags: php

hi to all m new to OOP PHP. i have following piece of code here in the following:

**test.php**

```
<?php
class test 
{
    private $dbhost;
    private $dbname;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbhost = 'localhost';
        $this->dbname = 'XXXX';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->pass = '';
    }
    public function open($obj)
    {
        $con = mysql_connect($this->dbhost,$this->user,$this->pass) or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db($this->dbname)or die(mysql_error());
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '".$obj."'") or die(mysql_error());

    }

}

?>
```

in the other file named test2.php i have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
    require_once('testClass.php');
    $obj = new test();
    $obj2 = 'user';
    $obj->open($obj2);
?>
```

and i got the following error:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user'' at line 1**

thnx in advance for help

Comment: If you are going to code OO, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/class.pdo.php), as it is OO and may be extended by your own classes. Currently you are re-inventing the wheel…

Comment: In addition to @feeela's comment, you're re-inventing the wheel, but you're also using deprecated functions to build it. See the red box on http://php.net/mysql_query? It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

**$obj should be tablename** and you doesn't need to put **single quote around table name.**

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$obj) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Edit:**

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row['userId'];
 }
```

Suggestion: Your query must be affected by mysql injection attack. It is really good to use PDO or Mysqli lib.

Comment: its working now accurately but there is another error like $show = mysql_fetch_array($query);
  foreach($show as $shown)
  {
   echo $shown['userId'];
  }
but it print now 11aa11nnpp00aa00aa22 instead of 1,2...which are in my table

Comment: hi GBD its working quiet accurately right now. but i have another question that the way in which i m trying to echo the output is working good in simple function. but here i had deal with the while function would you like to help me to understand the difference among both??

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");
$row = mysql_num_row($sql);
if($row > 0){
//do something
}else{
echo "No records found";
}
```

Comment: thanx Newbie for reply but i have plays with this a lot and m now going to try it in OOP PHP...

Comment: its ok. but they way in which i am working you can see the answer from GBD and mine conversation with him in comments. you may also can clear your point about the OOP PHP

Comment: [Try This](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/databaseobjects.html)

maybe this will help you goodluck to you. :)